# Unable to return the result of a function containing a Math object in console

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to Javascript so please forgive me if this seems like a silly question.

I defined a function called randomNumberGenerator, and in it is just one line of code. Basically, the purpose of it is to return a number between 0 and 2.

```
function randomNumberGenerator() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
};
```

However, when I tried to log the result of this function in my console, it shows me the outline (is that what it's called) of that function instead of a random number. You can see it here:

```
ƒ randomQuestionSelector() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
}
```

I tried assigning 'Math.round(Math.random() * 2)' to a simple variable, and logging that variable to the console. It worked as expected (I got a random number), so I'm confused why doing the same with a function doesn't.

Hope someone can help me out with this. Thank you!

Comment: You need to call the function (parenthesis after the name): `console.log( randomNumberGenerator() );` rather than `console.log( randomNumberGenerator );`

Comment: how you called the function?

Comment: Put your console log inside the function then call your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `console.log(randomNumberGenerator)` returned such a value is that you did not really invoke this function. You called the default `.toString()` method which exists on every object. And default implementation (which can be overriden) returns what you saw in the console. If you want to get the result of the function you need to use `()` operator which calls the function, like this:

`randomNumberGenerator()`

And to capture the returned value you can assign it to the variable, for example:

```
const random = randomNumberGenerator()
console.log(random);
```

That way you are calling the function and assigning the returned value to the new variable.

Comment: Oh my lord...can't believe I didn't realise that. Rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method. What you are likely doing is calling `console.log(randomNumberGenerator)` rather than `console.log(randomNumberGenerator())`